# Listing large lists of data

Tags: chat, chatbots

I am trying to build a chatbot to help me automate some of my administrative tasks.

In some cases I am trying to locate some data or I'm trying to see what data I configured in my system. Like "show users" (so that I can remember if I created a certain user or not).

Now my problem is that I have a large amount of users in my system - displaying them would take a huge amount of chat screen real estate.

How can I handled this? Any UX paradigms I can leverage? Any ways I can mitigate this scenario?
Any examples on how other chatbots are handling these scenarios?

Any thoughts would be welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

There is a UX paradigm of Cognitive Overload - Cognitive overload happens when too much information hinders decision-making and a good user experience in general.

Some tactics such as chunking and 'steps' safeguard against cognitive overload, or the problem of having to receive/interpret excess information.

The whole point of a chat bot is to get quick information ASAP, without having the need to deal with a real human (typically avoid the customer experience/ admin peeps).

I would suggest showing partial results (best match or top 5 values etc) and breaking up that information - in the form of an action button/link to another screen where all results can be displayed in a better format. Example below -

[image]